# Firebase cloud function typescript error "Not all code paths return a value"

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, tslint

I am using firebase cloud function and firestore transaction to decrease the available quantity of product based on purchases. At the time of deploy it returns the error "error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value"

Here is the code

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';


admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore()

exports.newOrder = functions.firestore
.document('orders/{orderId}')
.onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

    try {
        const data = snap.data();
        if (data === undefined) return null

        const itemList = data.list as Array<any>
        const productId: Set<string> = new Set<string>();

        itemList.forEach((item) => {
            productId.add(item.id)
        })
        return db.runTransaction(async t => {

            const promises: Promise<admin.firestore.DocumentSnapshot>[] = []
            productId.forEach(i => {
                const p = admin.firestore().doc('Products/' + i).get()
                promises.push(p)
            })
            const docs=await Promise.all(promises)
            docs.forEach(doc => {
                if (!doc.exists) {
                    return Promise.reject("Product deleted")
                }
            })
            itemList.forEach(j => {
                if (j.variation === '-') {
                    const available = docs[j.id].get('available')
                    const needed = j.quantity
                    if (available < needed) {
                        return Promise.reject("Product out of stock")
                    }
                }
                else {
                    const variations = docs[j.id].get('variation') as Map<string, any>
                    for (const i in variations.keys) {
                        if (i === j.variation) {
                            const needed = j.quantity
                            const available = docs[j.id].get('variation').get(i).get('quantity')
                            if (available < needed) {
                                return Promise.reject("Product out of stock")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            itemList.forEach(j => {
                if (j.variation === '-') {
                    const available = docs[j.id].get('available')
                    const needed = j.quantity
                    t.update(db.doc('Products/' + j.id), { 'available': available - needed })
                }
                else {
                    const variations = docs[j.id].get('variation') as Map<string, any>
                    for (const i in variations.keys) {
                        if (i === j.variation) {
                            const needed = j.quantity
                            const available = docs[j.id].get('variation').get(i).get('quantity')
                            t.update(db.doc('Products/' + j.id), { [`variation.${i}.quantity`]: available - needed })
                        }
                    }
                }
            })
            return Promise.resolve("Product quantity updated")
        })
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(`error ${error}`)
        return null
    }
});
```

Here is the error shown in deploy

```
 src/index.ts:30:30 - error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.

 30                 docs.forEach(doc => {
                            ~~~~~~~~

 src/index.ts:35:34 - error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.

 35                 itemList.forEach(j => {
                                ~~~~~~


 Found 2 error
```

How to solve the error.

2 loops mentioned in the error checks whether the products is deleted or not and product is out of stock or not. If it satisfies the condition i want to exit from the function. Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The probles is deeper than it may seem to be. You're possibly misunderstanding what does `return` statement do inside the `forEach`. The code is structured as if it was assumed to check if any of the `doc.exists` is false and return early if so, but written as this, it will return from the iteration callback.. and since `forEach` doesn't use the callback return value, the promise rejection remains unhandled.

The proper ways of achieving this result would be the following:

1) Just check directly what you need to check:

```
if (docs.findIndex(doc => !doc.exists) !== -1) {
    return Promise.reject("Product deleted");
}
```

2) Use the `for..in` or `for..of` loop instead of `forEach`:

```
for (doc of docs) {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        return Promise.reject("Product deleted")
    }
}
```

3) Use the `map` and `await` the result (not recommended, since you don't really need mapping):

```
await Promise.all(docs.map(doc => {
    if (!doc.exists) {
        return Promise.reject("Product deleted")
    }
    return null
})
```

Note that in this case any rejected promise inside the resulting array should trigger the rejection of the outer promise.

---

Side note: you don't ever need the explicit `Promise.reject()` call. As your function is async, you can simply `throw` something you'll use as an error - this will be transformed into promise rejection anyway.

Answer (score 5):

The error message is telling you that there are functions that don't return a value in all situations.  It's even telling which functions are violating this requirement.  Here's the first error:

```
 src/index.ts:30:30 - error TS7030: Not all code paths return a value.

 30                 docs.forEach(doc => {
                            ~~~~~~~~
```

It's telling you that the function you're passing to forEach is having a problem.

Here's the function:

```
        docs.forEach(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                return Promise.reject("Product deleted")
            }
        })
```

Note that the function isn't returning a value when `doc.exists` is true.  If you don't care about this situation, just return null:

```
        docs.forEach(doc => {
            if (!doc.exists) {
                return Promise.reject("Product deleted")
            }
            else {
                return null
            }
        })
```

Now the error goes away, because all code paths return a value. You can apply the same logic to the other error.

Answer (score 3):

This is a great example of Typescript imposing stupid conventions.
JavaScript function outputs `undefined` by default when there is no explicit return statement.  I recommend disabling return checking in `tsconfig.json`:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitReturns": false,
  }
}
```