# Not all code paths return value with multiple batch writes Google Firestore Cloud Function Typescript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

### Context

I have written a few cloud functions that execute batch writes properly. Within this instance, due to the database schema I have to search for documents that match the field of userA uid or userB uid.

### Schema/Functionality

This schema is not the most clever it could be and if there are any cleaner solutions please let me know. It is for the messaging aspect of our application. Where each document has a set of fields for userA and userB.

This function is triggered when a user changes their username and the documents within 'Conversations' collection with the user's data must be updated.

I have to perform two separate queries because I am searching through two different document **fields** that could possibly contain the id of the user who needs to update their information.

The batch write updates the documents with the new information for the instance of the user being userA or the instance they are userB.

### Problem

I thought that by created two separate batch writes for each query and return them properly it would "Return all code paths" however tsLint is telling me differently.

### What I've tried

Even when I try to account for non existsent documents as stated from here:
[Firebase cloud function typescript error "Not all code paths return a value"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54976561/firebase-cloud-function-typescript-error-not-all-code-paths-return-a-value)

I still am not returning all code paths properly.

Example:

```
//Changed from this
const batch = db.batch()
  querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
    batch.update(doc.ref, {
      profileImageURL: newProfilePic
    })
  })
  return batch.commit()

//To this
const batch = db.batch()
querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
  if (!doc.exists) {
    console.log("Document does not exists: " + doc.data())
  } else {
    batch.update(doc.ref, {
      userAusername: newUsername
    })
  }
})
return batch.commit()
```

Here is the full function

```
export const updateUserUsernameInConversations = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}')
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const { userId } = context.params

    const newUsername = change.after.data().username
    const oldUsername = change.before.data().username
    if (newUsername !== oldUsername) {
      const conversationsRef = db.collection('Conversations')
      const conversationQueryA = conversationsRef.where('userAuid', '==', userId)
      const conversationQueryB = conversationsRef.where('userBuid', '==', userId)

      conversationQueryA.get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            return null
          } else {
            const batch = db.batch()

            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              batch.update(doc.ref, {
                userAusername: newUsername
              })
            })
            return batch.commit()
          }
        })
 
      conversationQueryB.get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
          if (querySnapshot.empty) {
            return null
          } else {
            const batch = db.batch()
            querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
              batch.update(doc.ref, {
                userBusername: newUsername
              })
            })
            return batch.commit()
          }
        })
    } else {
      return null
    }
  })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem isn't with the batch.  The problem is that your larger Cloud Functions code doesn't return a promise that resolves when all the async work is complete ([see the documentation on that](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions)).  In fact, for the main `if (newUsername !== oldUsername)` block, your code returns nothing at all, and that's a problem.

Minimally, you code should go more like this:

```
    if (newUsername !== oldUsername) {
      // ...
      const promiseA = conversationQueryA.get()
        // ...
      const promiseB = conversationQueryB.get()
        // ...
      return Promise.all([promiseA, promiseB])
    }
    else {
      return null
    }
```

Now it will return a value no matter which primary code path is taken, and it will return a promise that resolves only after both chains of async work are complete.